# File-exclusion based on an array of prefixes

Tags: java

I am trying to remove files based on an array of prefixes, from files present in `sourceDirectory`. I am using `prefixFileFilter` to get the list of files with the prefixes. After that I am removing these from the original list.

Is there any better approach?

```
package sriram;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.PrefixFileFilter;

public class FileFilterExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
excludeFiles();
}

private static List<String> excludeFiles() {
String[] filesToBeExcluded = { "sri", "agnew" };
File sourceDirectory = new File(
        "C:\\Users\\sriram\\workspace1\\sample\\src");
String[] fileNames = sourceDirectory.list(new PrefixFileFilter(
        filesToBeExcluded));
List<String> listOfFiles = Arrays.asList(fileNames);
List<String> totalFiles = Arrays.asList(sourceDirectory.list());
totalFiles.removeAll(listOfFiles);
return totalFiles;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use java.io.FilenameFilter like:

```
    final List<String> excludedFiles = Arrays.asList(filesToBeExcluded);
    File[] totalFiles = sourceDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return !excludedFiles.contains(name);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 have had new features in **nio2** : *Files* et *Paths*, it manage also *Charset* problems.

Here he sample of *DirectoryStream.Filter*

```
static void newDirectoryStreamFilter(final Path file1, final Object filter1) {
        System.out.println(sepFin + "\nFiles.newDirectoryStreamFilter("
            + file1.getFileName() + "), filtre: " + filter1 + sepDeb);
        try {
            final DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(final Path file1) throws IOException {
                    for (String s : filesToBeExcluded)
                        if (file1.startsWith(s)) return false;
                        return true;
                }
            };
            try {
                for (final Path path : Files.newDirectoryStream(file1, filter)) {
                    System.out.format("%10d %s\n", Files.size(path),
                        path.toAbsolutePath());
                }
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using commons.io, you could use the [NotFileFilter](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/NotFileFilter.html).

and you will get:

```
private static List<String> getFileNamesWithoutExcludedPrefixes(File directory, String[] filesToBeExcluded) {
    return Arrays.asList(directory.list(new NotFileFilter(new PrefixFileFilter(filesToBeExcluded))));
}
```

(Argument checking could be added)

In your source:

```
totalFiles.removeAll(listOfFiles);
```

this can not work, because `Arrays.asList()` creates an immutable list.

You could change the line that creates the list to:

```
new ArrayList<String>(...);
```

if you need mutability.